# Find all instances of child models matching query

Tags: django, django-models

I have base class `Publication`, which `Book` and `Magazine` inherit from.

```
class Author(models.Model):
   pass

class Publication(models.Model):
   author = models.ForeignKey(Author)

class Book(Publication):
   pass

class Magazine(Publication):
   pass
```

I want to find all `Book` and `Magazine` objects with a certain author. Since the foreign key to `Author` is on the parent class `Publication`, my attempts at a query all return `Publication` objects rather than the child classes:

```
# Both of these return Publication objects, not Book/Magazine objects
Author.objects.get(pk=1).publication_set 
Publication.objects.get(author_pk=1)
```

Is there a way to get all instances of child classes with a certain author, without manually running the query for all child classes like `Book.objects.get(author_pk=1)` (in reality I have more than two child classes)?

Comment: Please mention the Django version you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to use an external package to get this kind of functionality. This looks like what you need: https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager

Specifically:

> ```
> from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager
>
> class Place(models.Model):
>     # ...
>     objects = InheritanceManager()
>
> class Restaurant(Place):
>     # ...
>
> class Bar(Place):
>     # ...
>
> nearby_places = Place.objects.filter(location='here').select_subclasses() 
> for place in nearby_places: 
>     # "place" will automatically be an instance of Place, Restaurant, or Bar
> ```